# CDO remapcon: verify mass conservation

Tags: python, python-xarray, cdo-climate

I have a netCDF file which I would like to regrid to a coarser grid and a smaller area.
I used `cdo remapcon` in order to conserve the mass of my variables and the output netCDF file looks promising so far.
However, I would like to make sure that the cdo function really worked as I hope it does and verify the mass conservation using python. Does somebody know how best to do that?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the grid area of the old and the new grid you can use `da.weighted(gridcell_area).sum()` . The method of rempconis described in "Jones, P. W. (1999). First‐ and second‐order conservative remapping schemes for grids in spherical coordinates."

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment and the article, it was very helpful! But I'm not sure if I understood correctly for the implementation, should `da_old.weighted(gridcell_area_old).sum()` = `da_new.weighted(gridcell_area_new).sum()` or rather `da_new.weighted(gridcell_area_old)` = `da_new.weighted(gridcell_area_new)` ?

Comment: The first one should do it.

Comment: It does indeed, thanks a lot!